# Minimum effort merging of two sets

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing, eigenvalues

I have the following problem.

I have two sequences of elements $A = [a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n]$ and $B = [b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_m]$. I can build a matrix $D[n \times m]$ where $d_{ij} = d(a_i,b_j)$

My greedy merging algorithm works as follows:

- For each iteration it takes the shortest distance pair and merges them.
- Then all the distances are recomputed (considering the merged pair)
- The process is repeated until each element of the two sequences is merged.
- Every time I merge a pair, I sum their distance. The final value of the algorithm is the total sum.

Now, I have to run it on a very large set of sequences.
I would like to have a fast, parallel, algorithm that provides an approximation or an upper bound of the sum.

I looked for eigenvector techniques, but I could not find any suitable algorithm.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: It looks similar to computing the [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). You might want to check the literature in Computer Vision/Graphics, where people use this type of algorithms, e.g., http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-8659.00236/abstract